# why wont tuples work?

Tags: c++, tuples

I'm trying to write a simple program using the c++ class tuple but, i can get it to work, I try passing  g++ -std=gnu++0x tuple.cpp the compile sends things back like tuple is an incomplete type and it doesn't recognize the function get(). 
here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <tuple> 

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

tuple<int, int> tup;

get<1>(tup) = 1;
get<2>(tup) = 2;

cout << "tup1:" << get<1>(tup) << "tup2:" << get<2>(tup) << endl;


return 0;


}
```

Comment: Just like everythign else in C++ use 0 based indexing, your tuple has 2 elements (idxs 0 and 1, *not* 1 and 2)

Comment: Always paste a complete error message.

Comment: "the c++ class tuple" -- `tuple` is **not** a class; it's a **template**. The two are fundamentally different, and if you muddle their meanings you'll suffer no end of pain.

Answer (score 3):

> it doesn't recognize the function `get()`

This is a compile time error implying that the tuple element index is not valid.

Tuple indexes start with 0, so that tuple of 2 elements has indexes 0 and 1.

```
tuple<int, int> tup;
get<2>(tup) ...; // <--- index 2 is not valid
```

Fix:

```
get<0>(tup) = 1;
get<1>(tup) = 2;
```

Comment: changing the indexes helped thanks!!